# Set the height of the ListControl of a DevExpress ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, devexpress

I have a DevExpress ComboboxEdit which can have a different number of items at any given time.

I have the list count set to 8 and it works fine.
If the list is actually less than 8 then it shows the extra blank lines.

How can I shrink the height based on the number of items in the list if less than 8?

Comment: Just change the max height every time you add or remove an item

Comment: You need to post some code to figure out what is the problem. Combobox limits it's height to the number of items in it's collection. There is a `DropDownHeight` that can be changed to limit/extend the size of the drop-down box. Plus there is an `ItemHeight` property. You can multiply number of items by ItemHeight and assign that to DropDownHeigth each time you assign new list of items to the Combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the combobox with foreach and remove when the value is null

Comment: There are no blank lines to remove.  I used to know a generic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!  Knew it was easy.

```
List<String> _reasons = new List<String>() {"a","b"};
if (_reasons.Count < Reason.Properties.DropDownRows)
    Reason.Properties.DropDownRows = _reasons.Count;
```